# How to apply PointPillar on my own dataset for 3d object detection?

Tags: object-detection, point-clouds, lidar

I have pointcloud data from Ouster lidar. I want to use Pointpillar on my dataset for 3d object detection. I can find some python codes (GitHubs) in this regard. However, all examples are based on Kitti dataset (pointcloud data, labels, 2d image, and calibration file). I just have pointcloud data with labels (*.txt/kitti format). How can I just use these files to apply pointpillar on my own dataset?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Best,
Abbas